# GRASS GIS v.net.iso prompt not calculating correct travel time distances

Tags: qgis, shapefile, grass-gis, distance, isochrone

When I run the v.net.iso command then export it into QGIS, the distance isochrones are not calculating my prompt distances (e.g. 1km, 2km, 5km).  [image]

1km distances (shown in green) are next to the 5km distances (purple), is close proximity of my starting location. Is this something to do with my road shapefile? I've tried another road file in another country and GRASS is calculating it correctly. Any ideas on how I can fix the problem?

Comment: Does the calculation use the geometry or did you use related attributes?

Comment: @markusN Found the answer on a previously similar topic. The road file needed cleaning. Seems to be working now through GRASS.

Comment: Great! BTW: a new helper addon is available now: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/manuals/addons/v.clean.ogr.html